# Use of vendor folder in web design

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am starting to build a website from scratch using python, django, and bootstrap. I have noticed that many times js, css, img. and fonts are stored in a folder vendor, such as:

```
/static/js/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js
/static/css/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

or something similar.

What is the benefit of this folder structure over something like:

```
/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

In the first example, when using the vendor folder as I have often seen, I would have to download bootstrap and unpack the downloaded folder into the js and css vendor sub-directories. In the second example, I can download bootstrap and drop the downloaded folder into /static without having to unpack anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It clearly marks which files are third-party libraries that should not be edited directly.

Comment: Makes sense. I think it will be worth the small amount of extra work and longer path names for increased organization. Although I know which files are third-party, if I hire developers they may not be sure if the files aren't in a vendor folder.

Answer (score 13):

The `vendor` folder is where you usually (I'm using the word 'usually' because it's not exactly a rule but more of a preference in the coding community with the purpose of having a semantic directory structure) keep third-party resources(icons, images, codes, you name it) as opposed to a `lib` (library) folder where you or the author of the site/application to be specific keep your original codes in.

So if I were to download and use the site/application in the hypothetical scenario above, I can then create relevant folders for each data type (`src/images for images, style/css for css, script/js for js, etc`) and move required assets from the lib folder to the new folders without having to edit the third-party codes (or other assets) thus making it easier to rollback on any changes made that cause errors and such.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Are you saying you would download the app and move the contents of the lib folder into a vendor folder? The website I am developing will never be downloaded and used by anybody else since it is going to be for my business, but I think I will use the vendor folder structure in case I hire developers in the future, so they know which files should not be modified.

Comment: No, the lib folder is for libraries exclusive to your site/app whereas your vendor folder has images, CSS, js, etc that are third-party resource. Developers that you hire should modify files that have been cloned in their respective data-type folder instead (e.g. instead of modifying a file name ABC.js from lib or vendor, they should copy paste that file to a new folder in the root directory called js/ where you can copy all your other js files too. The same applies to CSS, images, etc too.

Comment: "lib (library) folder where you or the author of the site/application to be specific keep your original codes in." I thought the author code of the app was put in a src (source) folder. And shouldn't lib be for, you know, libraries?

Comment: @JuanPerez I might be wrong but an app, framework, etc usually have files that you can edit but you shouldn't unless you know what you;'re doing and files that you are suppose to edit (e.g. in the context of say, a website, stylessheet, custom js, etc). The src folder is where those editable files should be in. Lib is where the files where you shouldn't edit are referenced from.